# MBassador only sends one message unless in debug mode

Tags: swing, debugging, mbassador

I have an MBassador 1.2.0 event but set up with a custom message type (interface `Message`):

```
private final MBassador<Message> bus = new MBassador<Message>(BusConfiguration.SyncAsync());
```

Whenever my Swing UI selects files, I add them to a map of file encapsulation objects and then send a message with the new values:

```
getBus().post(new FilesSelectedMessage(fileObjectMap.values())).asynchronously();
```

In my main panel class, I have a listener bean to listen for this message:

```
private class MessageHandler {
  @Handler
  public void handleFilesSelected(final FilesSelectedMessage message) {
    getLogger().info("new files selected; count {}", message.fileObjects().size());
  };
}
```

Of course I register that bean as a subscriber when my panel is initialized:

```
getBus().subscribe(new MessageHandler());
```

When I run this program normally, the first time I select files I get a log message telling me the number of files I selected. But if I go back and select the exact same file, I get no further log messages! (According to the code, even if no new files are added, an event should still be posted with the total number of files selected.)

Here's where it gets strange, if I put a breakpoint at the place where I post the messsage and one in the message handler, and then I run the application in debug mode, both breakpoints are hit every time I select a file, and the log message also gets printed every time! But then if I continue in debug mode and remove the breakpoint in the message handler, the application hits the breakpoint where the message is posted, but the log message is never printed. Even if I put the breakpoint *back* in the message handler, the message handler breakpoint is never hit again!

This behavior happens whether I post the message synchronously or asynchronously.

I understand that the way I've constructed MBassador is deprecated, and I've [asked](https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador/issues/94) about the proper way to create an event bus instance (as the online documentation is out of date and incorrect). But that still doesn't explain this odd behavior.

Any idea why only the first message goes through --- but functions fine as long as I'm in debug mode with breakpoints set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer hit me before I even got out of bed this morning. MBassador by default uses weak references, so I'm sure the listener bean was being garbage-collected. The breakpoint in the debugger must have kept it around longer. I only wonder why it hung around that long and didn't get released immediately. But in any case, I've verified that `@Listener(references = References.Strong)` on the bean class results in the expected behavior.